# Adding a apple-touch-icon not loading

Tags: javascript, html, safari, ejs

I have been trying to make the apple touch icon work with my website but it just won't. I put the link inside my head component, and I can see it clearly when I inspect my site in the  tag where it is meant to be. Any help would be appreciated. I us ejs btw.
head.ejs

```
<head>
    <title><%- title %> | Swiss Plus</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- FontAwesome CDN -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/global.css">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/swiss-plus.png" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- Apple Logo for iphones-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../public/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
</head>
```

home.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<%- include('../layouts/head.ejs', { title: "Home" }) %>

<body>
    <%- include('../layouts/navbar.ejs') %>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Popular videos of Swiss001</h1>
        <section class="grid">
            <% JSON.parse(videos).forEach(video => { %>
            <div class="card">
                <figure><img src="<%- video.thumbnails.medium.url %>" alt="<%- video.title %>" width="100%">
                    <figcaption><%- video.title %></figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<%- video.id %>" target="__blank" class="cta"
                        style="margin: 0 auto;"><button>Watch
                            this
                            video!</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% }) %>
        </section>
    </div>

    <%- include('../layouts/footer.ejs') %>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks alot y'all.

Comment: Are you sure this path is correct? `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../public/images/apple-touch-icon.png">`

Comment: yes, I'm sure thats the right path